# Qt application, hiding Mac dock & menu if there's only one display and show them if there are more

Tags: macos, qt, menu, display, dock

I'm building a full-screen application in Qt. If there is only one display, the Dock and Menu should be hidden but if there is more than one display,the Dock and Menu should only be hidden on the display showing the application and show one of the other displays.

I tried using

```
<key>LSUIPresentationMode</key>
<integer>4</integer>
```

but this also hides the Dock and Menu on every display instead of only the one containing the application.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There's no mechanism in Qt to do that. Whatever answer is to this question will be a generic Cocoa answer.